# The Battle of Puzzlings

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, lateral-thinking, matches

I present to you...

## The Battle of Puzzlings

Your task is to **turn 'one' into a letter representation of 1066** (the year of the [Battle of Hastings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Hastings)):

[image: Matches in the shape of the word ONE]

### Rules

- Fewest moves wins.
- All matches must be used.
- You cannot 'snap' matches to make multiple matches.

*You can use these [background](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d2/75/c6/d275c6625f501284ff269c0ad9993a2b.jpg) and [matchstick](http://www.pngpix.com/download/match-stick-png-transparent-image) images in your answer if you're into that sort of thing.*

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of matches we can move?

Comment: @benzene Nope...

Comment: I suggest that you make it a competition to see who can find the minimum amount of moves, otherwise this is too broad

Comment: 0 moves - the "one" actually says "DNE" - the answer does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is

> Use Roman numerals: 10 VI VI
>
> You have 4+3+4 = 11 matches. Use 1 for the 1, 4 for the 0 and 3 for each V1, for a total of 11.

And if we're counting moves:

> Four moves are needed. Move the left bar of the N to the left of the O to make the 1, then move all three arms of the E to form the second VI, leaving the back of the E as the I in the first VI.

Comment: Question edited after your answer but bravo anyway!

Answer (score 5):

I made in 4 moves:

> Using A1Z26 to represent 1066 as JFF (10, 6, 6)
>  [image]

Comment: Clever! Didn't think of doing it that way

Answer (score 4):

The minimum number of moves is

> **6** with a slanted letter or **7** without

1066 is

> MLXVI in roman numerals.

1066 has 11 matches - and so does that so:

> [image]

Taking either 6 or 7 moves.

This is the minimum because

> 'ONE' only shares 5 matchsticks in common with 'MLXVI'(slanted V version) - meaning that the other 6 have to be moved. Therefore 6 is the minimum. Here is a diagram:
>
>  [image]
>
> You can see there are only 5 matchsticks (black) that are shared - and the other 6 green matchsticks have to be moved to red.

---

PREVIOUS - Thanks HughMeyer for suggesting moving the overlay to the left for less moves

I previously thought it was 8:

> [image] [image]

Comment: This is the answer I was aiming for, but the question needs to be improved. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: @rybo111 I thought it might be from the number of matches. As to how it could be improved - to not make it so broad maybe say it has to be made out of letters? Not sure. There needs to be a 'challenge' of some sort

Comment: I've taken both your suggestions on board ('letter representation' and 'fewest moves'). Let's see if you can be beaten!

Comment: @rybo111 I know a way to check if this is the minimum - so will see

Comment: @rybo111 proven this is the minimum. see edit

Comment: I can see an arguable 7

Comment: And another arguable 6 :)

Comment: @rybo111 well, 8 without having letters touching anyway

Comment: My 'arguables' are based on the letters not touching, but with no set rules on alignment, angles and letter shape (which, in fairness, the question does not specify)

Comment: @rybo111 I think it should, otherwise that is probably too broad. Otherwise I could have just a jumble of those letters and claim I can do it in less than 8 - its not really correct

Comment: What if you shifted your overlay to use the vertical in E as the I?

Comment: @HughMeyers [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Zam.png) ? I think that works, and thats 7! Thanks!

Comment: @HughMeyers I can actually make that a 6 if it has a slanted V

Comment: @rybo111 Hugh has helped me find a definite 7 and a possible 6 by moving the letters left - see edit

Comment: You can also do 6 by looking at it upside down and making the N into a crooked M. Not sure if that's cheating.

Answer (score 1):

A (perhaps cheap) solution in 2 moves:

> Use Hexadecimal. 1066 in Hex is 0x42A. Then, move the matches like so:
>
>   [image]
>
>   If you rotate your point of view, you'll find the characters 4, 2, and A stacked one on top of the other:
>
>   [image]
>
>   Admittedly, the 2 looks more like a Z, but is still somewhat believable.

Comment: I don't believe it's right, but it's clever and unorthodox. I like it.